# Pip install Matplotlib error with virtualenv

Tags: python, matplotlib, pip, virtualenv

I am trying to install matplotlib in a new virtualenv.

When I do:

```
pip install matplotlib
```

or

```
pip install http://sourceforge.net/projects/matplotlib/files/matplotlib/matplotlib-1.1.0/matplotlib-1.1.0.tar.gz
```

I get this error:

```
building 'matplotlib._png' extension

gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fPIC -  DPY_ARRAY_UNIQUE_SYMBOL=MPL_ARRAY_API -DPYCXX_ISO_CPP_LIB=1 -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I. -I/home/sam/django-projects/datazone/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I. -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/_png.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/_png.o

src/_png.cpp:10:20: fatal error: png.h: No such file or directory

compilation terminated.

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Anyone have an idea what is going on?

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: You may also see `The following required packages can not be built: freetype, png` which is the same error in (I think) a newer version of `pip`.

Answer (score 178, accepted):

Building Matplotlib requires `libpng` (and `freetype`, as well) which isn't a python library, so `pip` doesn't handle installing it (or `freetype`).

You'll need to install something along the lines of `libpng-devel` and `freetype-devel` (or whatever the equivalent is for your OS).

See the [building requirements/instructions](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/installing.html#build-requirements) for matplotlib.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I finally got it working by installing the following dependencies in ubuntu: `libpng-dev`, `libjpeg8-dev`, `libfreetype6-dev`.

Comment: `sudo apt-get build-dep python-matplotlib` also does the trick!

Comment: It may work, but note that it wants to install quite a few packages (more than can fit in this comment box), but about 0.6 GB worth of packages.

Comment: On my debian (wheezy/unstable) system it was failing even with `libfreetype6-dev` installed. It turned out that I also needed `pkg-config` installed.

Comment: I actually have libfreetype6-dev intalled on ubuntu 14.04. Matplotlib seems not to be picking it.

Comment: Also check the versions you have installed are the ones stated in the requirements. I already had png (libpng) and freetype installed and "yum" said that they were already at the latest version. However, the version was still lower than the requirements so I had to go to the package's website and install by hand. That fixed it for me.

Answer (score 52):

To generate graph in png format you need to Install following dependent packages

```
sudo apt-get install libpng-dev
sudo apt-get install libfreetype6-dev
```

Ubuntu https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/libpng12-0/
or using following command

```
sudo apt-get install libpng12-0
```

Answer (score 31):

As I have struggled with this issue twice (even after fresh kubuntu 15.04 install) and installing freetype did not solve anything, I investigated further.

**The solution:**
[From github issue:](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/3029/)

> This bug only occurs if pkg-config is not installed;
>   a simple
>   `sudo apt-get install pkg-config`
>   will shore up the include paths for now.

After this installation proceeds smoothly.

Comment: Same here. pip install matplotlib gave me error: `IMPORTANT WARNING: pkg-config is not installed. matplotlib may not be able to find some of its dependencies.` Freetype shows not installed. I just did `brew install pkg-config` and was able to get by.

Comment: This is also the problem on Bash on Ubuntu on Windows Insider Preview

Answer (score 27):

As a supplementary, on Amazon EC2, what I need to do is:

```
sudo yum install freetype-devel
sudo yum install libpng-devel
sudo pip install matplotlib
```

Comment: It is recommended to install a package to a virtual environment, which makes `pip` so nice.  Hence `sudo pip install` negates most of the usefulness that pip brings to the table.

Answer (score 8):

On OSX I was able to get matplotlib to install via:

```
pip install matplotlib==1.4.0
```

only after I ran:

```
brew install freetype
```

Answer (score 6):

Under Windows this worked for me:

```
python -m pip install -U pip setuptools
python -m pip install matplotlib
```

(from https://matplotlib.org/users/installing.html)

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo apt-get install libpng-dev libjpeg8-dev libfreetype6-dev
```

worked for me on Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: I needed `sudo apt-get install pkg-config` first though.

Comment: @RahulChauhan: Please post your [alternative solution](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17336490) as a separate answer instead of trying to edit it into someone else's answer.

Answer (score 0):

None of the above answers worked for me in Mint, so I did:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential g++
```

Answer (score 0):

If on MacOSx try

```
xcode-select --install
```

This complies `subprocess 32`, the reason for the failure.

Answer (score 0):

To reduce the required packages to install you just need

```
apt-get install -y \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libxft-dev && \
    pip install matplotlib
```

and you will get the following packages locally installed

```
Collecting matplotlib
  Downloading matplotlib-2.2.0-cp35-cp35m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (12.5MB)
Collecting pytz (from matplotlib)
  Downloading pytz-2018.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (509kB)
Collecting python-dateutil>=2.1 (from matplotlib)
  Downloading python_dateutil-2.6.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (194kB)
Collecting pyparsing!=2.0.4,!=2.1.2,!=2.1.6,>=2.0.1 (from matplotlib)
  Downloading pyparsing-2.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (56kB)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.10 in /opt/conda/envs/pytorch-py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from matplotlib)
Collecting cycler>=0.10 (from matplotlib)
  Downloading cycler-0.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting kiwisolver>=1.0.1 (from matplotlib)
  Downloading kiwisolver-1.0.1-cp35-cp35m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (949kB)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.7.1 in /opt/conda/envs/pytorch-py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from matplotlib)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /opt/conda/envs/pytorch-py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools-27.2.0-py3.5.egg (from kiwisolver>=1.0.1->matplotlib)
Installing collected packages: pytz, python-dateutil, pyparsing, cycler, kiwisolver, matplotlib
Successfully installed cycler-0.10.0 kiwisolver-1.0.1 matplotlib-2.2.0 pyparsing-2.2.0 python-dateutil-2.6.1 pytz-2018.3
```

Answer (score 0):

Installing `matplotlib==3.3.3` with `Python 3.9` resolved the issue for me. [Reference](https://github.com/duo-labs/cloudmapper/issues/803#issue-743365536)