# c++: Matplotlib pyplot show() giving SegFault

Tags: python, c++, matplotlib

I want to create a log-log plot using pyplot, but have trouble when calling `plt.show()`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xVec = [...]
yVec = [...]

plt.figure()
plt.loglog(xVec,yVec,'.',label='This is my test plot')
plt.xlabel('x axis')
plt.ylabel('y axis')

plt.show()
```

I am running this code from C++ via:

```
Py_Initialize();
Py_SimpleString(pythonCode.str().c_str());
Py_Exit(0);
```

where `pythonCode` is a `stringstream` containing the Python code above. The code runs if I don't include the `plt.show()` line, but of course no plot shows up.

The `matplotlibrc` config file shows that the backend is **TkAgg**, which shouldn't give problems as indicated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19721385/matplotlib-pyplot-does-not-show-output-no-error) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7534453/matplotlib-does-not-show-my-drawings-although-i-call-pyplot-show). I've tried adding `plt.close()` after the last line in the code above, but the error persists.

Perhaps the most surprising thing is this: I've also tried running the code in a separate Python script (with `plt.show()`), and **the plot appears correctly!** Does anyone have any idea about what's going on? Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I have also tried `pylab` instead of `pyplot`, with the same results. Do I need to compile the program with a certain `python` module to link the libraries properly?

Comment: `PyEval_InitThreads();`  right after `Py_Initialize();` might be in order just in case threads are somehow used.

Comment: @J.J.Hakala Not using threads for this code :(